# ファイル転送での文字化けについて

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, scp

Windows10からVirtualBox上のUbuntuにscpコマンドでファイルを転送しました。
すると、ファイル内の日本語がUbuntu上で文字化けしてしまいます。
理由と対策が知りたいです。ご教示お願い致します。

Comment: メモ帳で新規ファイルを作って転送したら化けないと思うので確認してください。もし化けなかったとしたら転送したファイルに問題があるだけということになります。

Answer (score 0):

どうやら文字コードが違っていたようです。
アップロードされたUbuntu側でコマンドで文字コードを変換しました。